# How to get project id for an existing Azure DevOps project using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

Am working on **PowerShell** script where I am trying to get project id of an existing one in **Azure** **DevOps** account. For that, am used following script:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "l7zybu-XXX-XXXX-XXXXX"
$OrganizationName = "OrgName"
$projectName = "XXXXXX"

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$UriOrga = "https://$($OrganizationName).visualstudio.com/" 
$UriOrga
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader | where({ $_.name -eq $projectName })
```

After running this script am not getting any type of Output in logs, it's just executing? Could you please help me to find solution for this.

Comment: That's because you're filtering the results.with `| where({ $_.name -eq $projectName })` and there isn't a match. Remove that and see what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get project id for an existing Azure DevOps project using PowerShell?

You could try the following PowerShell Sample:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "PAT"

$OrganizationName = "organizaitonName"
$projectName = "Projectname"

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$UriOrga = "https://$($OrganizationName).visualstudio.com/" 
$UriOrga
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 


$Project = $response.value | where { $_.Name -eq $projectName }

$id = $Project.id

echo $id
```

The response returned by Rest API is in **Json format**, so you can get the json response first, and then directly obtain the corresponding project id through comparison