# get project id for an existing Azure DevOps project using C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I need to create a C# project that allows me create, update, delete team project in Azure Dvops on-prem. I came across some samples at  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples.git but it is so complicated to understand and there is no guide or instructions on how to use.
I tried first to create a method to delete a team project but I always need the id of the project which I am not able to figure out how to get this using Teamproject object or ProjectInfo from
`enter code here`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi
I came across a thread here

> get project id for an existing Azure DevOps project using PowerShell?
> [How to get project id for an existing Azure DevOps project using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265335/how-to-get-project-id-for-an-existing-azure-devops-project-using-powershell)

which shows how to do it in powershell which works fine.
So the question is: how I can do the same thing in C# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples based on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/ package. To use it, you may generate PAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

Connect to your org:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceURL), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
```

Get Project Client:

```
ProjectClient = Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
```

Then use `GetProjects`, `QueueCreateProject`, `QueueDeleteProject`. The project operations you may find in this part: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/ProjectsAndTeams/ProjectsSample.cs

Update:

To get the project Id, you may use `GetProjects` method:

```
var projectId = (from p in ProjectClient.GetProjects().Result
                                             where p.Name == projectName
                                             select p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already successfuly ran the Quickstarts\dotnet\WitQuickStarts project but all operations in CreateProject, DeletePrtoject......uses a mecanism based on the creatred project but not in this project nor in the ClientLibrary\Samples shows what I need to do. OK, I will try to follow your code but for example, QueueDeleteProject needs id  as follows Guid operationId = projectClient.QueueDeleteProject(project.Id).....so from where following your code I can get this ID?

Comment: @eliassal I`ve updated my answer. Here you may find additional examples:  [41.TFRestApiAppManageTeamProjects](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/blob/master/41.TFRestApiAppManageTeamProjects/TFRestApiApp/Program.cs)

Comment: So many thanks Shamrai for your help, it works fine and I was able to finish he delete function. However, I tried to find a list of what the list of types  Function GetClientcan have but MS docs doesnt list on their page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dn424867(v=vs.120). I saw a couple of types <ProjectHttpClient> and <WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>, so I need to find out the list of those types, thanks again